# Recommendation for USB based 802.11n network adapter with native driver support in Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, wireless-networking, hardware-rec, 802.11n

Can you recommend a USB based 802.11n network adapter that has native driver support for Linux?

In particular,

- I don't want to use ndiswrapper.
- The card must support WPA (preferably through WPA supplicant).  I believe you can't do class N without WPA.  Certainly my router doesn't support WEP at high bandwidth.
- I'd prefer the drivers for the chipset to be available in the "current" kernel.  I'm ok with compiling and installing separate drivers if necessary however.

As an example, one product that matches my requirements is a Belkin device with the Ralink RT2870 chipset.  Unfortunately Belkin seem to have changed chipsets in later versions...

Thanks in advance for any assistance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout the Asus USB-N11 - 802.11n adapter. It has linux support.

http://it-review.net/article/news/news/World_s_First_USB_Adapter_with_EZLink_WPS,_WiFi_Protected_Setup_

http://www.everythingusb.com/asus-usb-n11-wireless-n-usb-adapter-15063.html

Comment: An ASUS product page: http://sg.asus.com/products.aspx?l1=29&l2=172&l3=745&l4=63&model=2401&modelmenu=1  Drivers are available here.

Answer (score 2):

There is a list at [the official Linux Wireless wiki](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Devices/USB). Each distribution should also have its own page, see for instance Ubuntu's [Wireless Cards Supported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported). These lists might not tell if the device can do 802.11["draft-"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft-n)n, but should tell you which devices work, and how well they work.

Comment: Hey CesarB: Thanks for your response.  In my research (yep, I did spend some time on this first ;) I came across this page.  As you point out, it solves the problem of compatibility once you know that your device is 802.11n.

Comment: You are right about the "draft" thing.  It hasn't been a problem yet though - I have got one draft adapter talking to my draft router in 802.11 with a measured bandwidth 5 x higher than 802.11g.

Comment: @kwutcha: all draft-n devices should be compatible to other draft-n devices, but we have no way of knowing how compatible they will be to the final 802.11n, since the standard has not come out yet.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.thinkpenguin.com/ has 802.11N USB wifi cards that are supported in all the recent distributions including Ubuntu 9.10, 10.04, and 10.10, as well as free distributions like Trisquel 4.01

Comment: Thanks Jamie.  Do you have any idea what chipset they use?